# Can the Jquery Cookie plugin only read cookies that it sets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-mobile, jquery-cookie

Can the Jquery Cookie plugin only read cookies that it sets?

I am using an `IFrame` to display a page inside a `jQuery Mobile` page (`date-role="page`). The Iframe, uses a page that is asp.net forms authenticated.  I want to check if the cookie exists and has not expired  before navigating to the page.  This way I can handle the login process only if the cookie does not exist.  Is this possible?

I am trying to read the cookie as such

```
alert( $.cookie("example") );
```

Comment: No should be ok with all, all the plugin does is provide a jQuery like API to the native cookie functionalities.

Comment: Was the cookie set on the same domain as you are attempting to read it from?

Comment: @Rory Its a different domain.  This wont always be the case however

Comment: That's the problem then in this case - you can only read cookies on the same domain as they are set.

Comment: @Rory do you fancy chalking all the above up as an answer instead of comments then and I'll tick it off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Its a different domain. This wont always be the case however

This is the problem in this case - cookies can only be read from the same domain as they were set. This is a security feature which is present in every browser.